# How to redefine csquotes quotations in british English style?

Tags: csquotes

Have a look at the following code. I wonder why it isn't working with the single quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\newfontfamily\newcmbook{NewCM10-Book}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquoteleft}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook `}}% Doesn't work.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquoteright}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook '}}% Doesn't work.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquotedblleft}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ``}}% Works.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquotedblright}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ''}}% Works.
}

\begin{document}
\enquote{abcd}

\enquote*{abcd}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with LuaLaTeX from fully updated TeX Live 2023. Both the fonts are available with the TeX distribution. Here is the output:

[image: 1]

---

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
csquotes.sty    2022-09-14 v5.2n context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2022-09-14 v5.2n csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
fontspec.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2023-02-02 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2023-03-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-luatex.def    2023-03-30 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
fontspec-luatex.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles`? This looks OK for me with up-to-date LaTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright File-list and output added.

Comment: Any updates @JosephWright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use proper Single Quotes, i.e. `U+2018 Left Single Quotation Mark` and `U+2019 Right Single Quotation Mark` instead of apostrophes and grave accents (backticks), everything works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\newfontfamily\newcmbook{NewCM10-Book}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquoteleft}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ‘}}% Works.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquoteright}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ’}}% Works.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquotedblleft}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ``}}% Works.
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquotedblright}{TU}{%
  {{\newcmbook ''}}% Works.
}

\begin{document}
\enquote{abcd}

\enquote*{abcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah!! Didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot.